# Php how to loop through multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do you loop through a multidimensional array as follows and get the keys and their values by the key name?

```
 $leaveTypes = (object) [
                 [
                   "name" => "Holiday",
                   "colour" => "#cc6699",
                   "deducted" => true,
                 ],
                 [
                   "name" => "Sick Leave",
                   "colour" => "#996666",
                   "deducted" => false,
                ]
             ];

     foreach($leaveTypes as $leaveType)
     {
           $someVariable = $leaveType->name;

     }
```

The above gives me an error: trying to get property of non object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing arrays and not objects so you should use the array syntax:

```
foreach($leaveTypes as $leaveType)
{
    $someVariable = $leaveType['name'];
}
```

**EDIT**: you changed your question a lot with the `(object)` cast, in this case you need an array of objects so you can loop thru them:

```
$leaveTypes = [
    (object) [
        "name" => "Holiday",
        "colour" => "#cc6699",
        "deducted" => true,
    ],
    (object) [
        "name" => "Sick Leave",
        "colour" => "#996666",
        "deducted" => false,
    ]
];
foreach($leaveTypes as $leaveType)
{
    $someVariable = $leaveType->name;
}
```

The two solutions are pratically the same, associtive arrays are fine.

Comment: even when i cast to object it still throws the same error?

Comment: You need an array of objects, you have to cast every single item to object if you wish to iterate.

Comment: the following would work `json_decode(json_encode($array));`